# Integrating Angulartics with Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-analytics, ionic-framework

I am trying to use Angulartics with Ionic Framework. However, nothing is tracking on google analytics. Here is how a set it up.

1. index.html.slim file

   ```
   <script src="lib/angulartics/src/angulartics.js">
   <script src="lib/angulartics/src/angulartics-ga-cordova.js">
   ```

   javascript:

   ```
   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)
     {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function()   {
       (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();
       a=s.createElement(o),
       m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
       a.async=1;
       a.src=g;
       m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
   ga('create', '#{ENV['GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID']', { 'cookieDomain': 'none' });`
   ```
2. Added it to my angular module

   ```
   angular.module('app', ['angularMoment', 'angulartics', 'angulartics.google.analytics.cordova', 'ngCordova'])`
   ```
3. Adde $analyticsProvider to my config in routes

   ```
   .config ($analyticsProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
   ```

I am not getting any data on my google analytics Dashboard.  Can someone please explain how to install Angulartics in my ionic project.

Comment: `Ionic` by defaults uses `AngularJS`. So u don't need to install Angular separately. Check in your `bower.json` file to confirm whether `AngularJS` is installed or not.

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look at the angulartics-ga-cordova script file here: https://github.com/luisfarzati/angulartics/blob/master/src/angulartics-ga-cordova.js

On line 48, it is expecting the GAPlugin.

```
var analytics = window.plugins && window.plugins.gaPlugin;
```

You will need to add this script to your main index file. https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin

Then you can add your google tracking info like this.

```
myApp.config ($analyticsProvider, googleAnalyticsCordovaProvider) ->
    $analyticsProvider.firstPageview(true)
    googleAnalyticsCordovaProvider.trackingId = GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID
```

Also, if you are using phonegap build, you will need to add the following line to your config.xml file.

```
<gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.gaplugin" />
```

Comment: gaplugin is not working on Android if anyone got it to work